# Сколько ребер необходимо и достаточно, чтобы граф был связным?

Tags: графы, теория

Рассмотрим ориентированный граф на 6ти вершинах.

а) Сколько ребер необходимо, чтобы он был связным?

б) А достаточно?

Comment: Сильно или слабо связный? Двусторонние рёбра считаются за одно или два? А вообще, вопрос на маткод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вопросе явно чего-то не хватает, а именно, какая связность нужна?
Что касается минимального числа ребер, то 5.